# Getting the last half of string written on backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a certain string, or several strings.
For example:

```
a = '12345678'
b = '123456789'
```

I'm using Python 3.2. I'm trying to get the last half of a string written on backwards. If a string has an odd amount of characters, the middle character is discarded. So, what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
a_out = '8765'
b_out = '9876'
```

The way I do it is the following:

```
a_back = a[::-1]
a_out = a_back[0:len(a_back)//2]
```

The question is: is there a shorter way to do this? Can it be done in one operation instead of two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate the index and reverse the string at the same time:

```
>>> a[:-(len(a)+1)//2:-1]
'8765'
>>> b[:-(len(b)+1)//2:-1]
'9876'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just make it a one-liner:

```
a_out = a[::-1][0:len(a)//2]
```

It would be nice if you could do fancy indexing in a string, like we do in a `numpy` array, then another solution would be:

```
a_out = a[ range(len(a)-1, len(a)//2-1, -1) ] # NOT POSSIBLE
```

@jamylak suggested to use 'itemgetter' to accomplish an equivalent for fancy indexing in an efficient way:

```
from operator import itemgetter
items = [0,3,2,1,0,0,2,3,]
a_out = ''.join( itemgetter( *items )(a) )
#14321134
```

Comment: The `numpy` solution to this problem can be solved in exactly the same way as the solution by  @NolenRoyalty

Comment: Thank you, for me it was good to learn that the index could be calculated in this way. But the fancy indexing accept also something like [0, 3, 2, 1, 5], does not have to be within a range pattern

Comment: That will however be slower, and you **can** achieve this in Pure python with `from operator import itemgetter` `itemgetter(*list_of_indices)(a)`

Comment: That is also great to know! Thank you! Wouldn't you mind if I updated the answer with this option?... have you tried this with strings?

Answer (score 1):

Using a method:

```
a = '12345678'
b = '123456789'

def method(x):  
    return x[:-(len(x)+1)//2:-1]

print method(a)
print method(b)

>>> 
8765
9876
```

Comment: `len(x) // 2`, as OP is using Python 3.